# How do i limit the amount of objects are instantiated?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've looked through the code and tried different approaches multiple times, but i just can't seem to get it to work.

It works properly twice, then its stops working properly the third time.

I want 1 object to be instantiated each time, but instead on the third time it spawns 30, which is bad.

I want it to spawn 1 object each time.

So i used this script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Attack : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform playerPos = null;
    private float playerDist;
    private GameObject projectileEnemyClone;
    public GameObject projectileEnemyPrefab;

    private float kickBack = 10;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    private int bulletCount = 0;

    private bool canshoot = true;



    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        if (canshoot == true)
        {

            projectileEnemyClone = Instantiate(projectileEnemyPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

            canshoot = false;
        }



    }

   private void Respawn()
    {
        canshoot = true; ;
    }
    private void ShootLeft()
    {
        Shoot();

        projectileEnemyClone.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        projectileEnemyClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.right * -10);

        kickBack *= -1;

        rb.AddForce(transform.right * kickBack);



        Destroy(projectileEnemyClone, 1);

        if (!canshoot)
        {
            Invoke("Respawn", 2);
        }





    }

    private void ShootRight()
    {
        Shoot();


        projectileEnemyClone.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        projectileEnemyClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.right * 10);



        rb.AddForce(transform.right * kickBack);

        Destroy(projectileEnemyClone, 1);

        Invoke("Respawn", 2);




    }




    void Update () {
        playerDist = playerPos.position.x - transform.position.x;




        if (playerDist <= (3) && playerDist >= (-3))

        {


            if (playerDist < (0))
            {



                    Invoke("ShootLeft", 1);

            }
            else
            {


                 Invoke("ShootRight", 1); 







            }


        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Create a timer variable which dictates the attack's rate of fire, reset it each time you shoot, and don't allow shooting again until enough time has elapsed.

Comment: Define "each time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Invoke(), you should create a timer that controls your Shoot() function.

```
float shootCooldown = 0.1f;
float shootTimer = 0;
bool justShot = false;

void Update()
{
    if(!canShoot)
    {
        shootTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(shootTimer >= shootCooldown)
        {
            shootTimer = 0;
            canShoot = true;
        }
    }    
}

void Shoot()
{
    if(canShoot)
    {
        Shoot();
        canShoot = false;
    }
}
```